# Can't paste an image onto another image with PIL properly

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have this image:

[image]

that I'm trying to paste on to this one:

[image: image_2[![][2]]

I want to get rid of the black background (so I'm assuming "make it transparent"?).

I tried applying a black mask, but 
the result is this:

[image]

I'm not quite understanding how to use a mask properly. 
I thought creating  a black mask would get rid of the black portions.

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(r'..jpg')
image_2 = Image.open(r'...jpg')

image_copy = image.resize((300,300)).copy() #fish image
mask=Image.new('L', (300,300), color=0)


position = ((200,100))

image_2.paste(image_copy, position, mask = mask)
image_2.save('testing_1.png')
```

EDIT: Playing around with the code a bit more I'm able to overlay the image onto the background,
but it still has the black background surrounding it.

I would like to get RID of the black background.

[image]

Comment: Does it have alpha? Are you trying to blend ? or do alpha blending?

Comment: No blending. Just paste it onto the other image, but without the black border. I'm not really sure about the alpha part.

Comment: Can you paste an image how the end result should look like?

Comment: Anyhow...any operations you do like `add` or `overlay` or `mask` they need to have the same resolution.

Comment: @user1767754 I wish I could paste the end result, but cropping the image produced a black border, which I don't really know how to get rid off (without pixel counting), and the black border is what I want to get rid off.  I updated the OP with image 4.  Thank you.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the black parts you should use `numpy` remove the blacks, which might remove as well blacks in the image though.